# Run multiple unittest test files at once

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing, pycharm

In my project I created a unittest test file for each Python file. For example, I have file `component.py` and its accompanying `test_component.py`. Similarly for `path.py` and `test_path.py`, etc.

However, since these files depend on each other it is possible that a change in one file affects another, thus if I change something I need to rerun all my testfiles. For now, I have to do this manually.  Is it possible to run all these test files at once with only one handling? Maybe call them from an extra file? I want however still use the testsuite as before (see the image below).

I am using Python 2.7 and JetBrains' PyCharm.

[image]

Comment: Why aren't you using something like pytest?

Comment: I did not know pytest, but it seems interesting. Any experience with it on windows or ubuntu?

Comment: Yes, and -- without going into too much detail -- I absolutely recommend it.

Comment: Thank you, I will give it a try!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible to run all tests located in some folder.

Go to `Run - Edit Configurations`, select or create run configuration for tests and specify path to folder.

[image]

Comment: The answer I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using [Pytest](http://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/).

Another alternative is to have a separate file that calls tests or instantiates classes from each test file. Based on the returns it calls the next test.

You also might have a need store information in a .txt file. You could write and read to a file that holds your test variables, conditions, etc.